# Refused to load the image because it violates content-securtiy-policy -- Cordova

Tags: cordova, content-security-policy

I am trying to deploy my app following the code-push doc. I then added the following content-security to my app index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src https://codepush.azurewebsites.net 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Immediately i added, my app does not run again. When i run my cordova browser. I saw many errors in the console. It turns out my styles files referenced from github, my images referenced from mysite.com/... and my other external scripts, goopleapis are my security policy to below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

It now works fine. My question is, What is the security ramification ? Should i leave it that way?  How better should i do this ? Any help or opinion would be appreciated. I am worried leaving * may allow the attacks intended to stopped.

Answer (score 13):

You're right, leaving your CSP like this might make things easier for an attacker. The main idea behind using a CSP is url whitelisting as described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#source-whitelists).

By whitelisting everything with the `*` wildcard you allow an attacker to load code (and execute) from everywhere once he is able to inject code into your application. Check out the linked article on this, it's a lot better than what I'm writing here ;)

So what's the right way to do this?

1. Find out what domains you want to whitelist and what kind of [resources](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#policy-applies-to-a-wide-variety-of-resources) this domain provides.
2. Get rid of the wildcard and whitelist **exactly** those domains for exactly those resources you need. Let's, for example, take a look at your stylesheets from GitHub. You will have to add GitHub as a trustworthy domain for styles somewhat like this: `style-src 'self' https://github.com 'unsafe-inline';`

Note: Be careful with the `default-src` policy as it overrides the other policies. And when it comes to whitelisting images, you might have to add the `data:` keyword like so: `img-src 'self' http://somedomain.com data:;`

[Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) is quite good if you're looking for an overview of all the policies and keywords...

Comment: The docs really are helpful. Check them out if this question doesn't answer everything.

Answer (score 3):

solved with:

```
script-src 'self' http://xxxx 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
```

Comment: This solved my problem loading images in Cordova + Phaser3

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' http://localhost:5000 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`

Comment: sorry for the probably stupid question but when you wrinte http:/xxxx should it be the URL of my website?