# Cordova - CSP refuses to load media blob

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, content-security-policy

I'm trying to load get some audio data from an HTTP POST request and then play it from an Android device. This is the code that handles that operation:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', encodeURI(myURLString), true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(evt) {
    var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'audio/wav'});
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    audio.play();
};
xhr.send(myData);
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Refused to load media from 'blob:file:///d181cef8-136d-4dab-b5c6-598a0481755c' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src *".
```

I'm not sure how to set this directive to allow this file to be played, and I can't get this to work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Removing the directive altogether appears to work, but it hardly seems like the correct solution. Is it?

Comment: You might need to add the `blob:` modifier to your media-src directive like `media-src * blob:`. [Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/media-src)

Comment: @Phonolog Perfect! Thanks for the link too. I'll accept this as an answer if you post it as one.

Comment: Great :) I added an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding the `blob:` modifier to your content security policy should fix the issue. Your media-src directive could look something like this: `media-src * blob:` assuming it was `media-src *` before.

Further information on the media-src directive can be found in [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/media-src).

---

Also, note that using `*` wildcards is generally not a good idea. It undermines the idea of whitelisting, which is [described here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/#source-whitelists). I also answered a question on how to get rid of wildcards [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37939070/5730444).

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with electron app below meta tag solved my problem

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' file: data: blob: filesystem:; default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```