# jquery library not found (Google Extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head> 
<script src="test.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquer‌​y.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body>

<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="consult" placeholder="consult">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="url">
<button type="submit" >Send Data </button>
</form>



</body>

</html>
```

> here is my code html updated

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("ext loaded")
    $("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var consult = $("input#consult").val()
    var url = $("input#url").val()
    console.log(consult, url)
    // alert(consult+ url)
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:"https://www.jbhired.com/admin/server/submitSearch.php",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          crossDomain: true,
          data : {
            consult: consult, 
            url: url
          },

        })
    });
});
```

> this is js file updated

```
 {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "One test",
    "description": "test.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "pic1.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "script" : "test.js"
    },

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'http://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

> and this is menifest file
>
> error is
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at test.js:4
>
> popup.html:1 Refused to load the script
>   'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquer%E0%B9%82%E2%82%AC%C2%8C%E0%B9%82%E2%82%AC%C2%8By.min.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: what is the error

Comment: really sorry i forget to show an error

Comment: here is an error   " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < "

Comment: in which line ?

Comment: also add ; to each ending statement

Comment: looks fine to me, probably some other HTML parsing error on a part of your page which you hadn't post here

Comment: Check your internet connection because you use jquery CDN.

Comment: @Rahul  in line 1

Comment: @vsync  really sorry i'm noob at coding   here is my menifest.json                  {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "One test",
    "description": "test.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "pic1.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "script" : "test.js"
    },
   
    
}

Comment: @vsync and here is  html file                                                  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="consult" placeholder="consult">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="url">
  
<button type="submit" >Send Data </button>
</form>
<script src="test.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

Comment: post your file names

Comment: @JaydeepMor  i checked it but i think it is  not problem about my internet connection

Comment: @Rahul  test.js    i really sorry again i'm not good at english but i wil try

Comment: You need to create a html file first and in that file you need to move your js file

Comment: @Rahul let me show you for awhile

Comment: @Rahul you mean move all file or just library?

Comment: copy this line - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> to your html file

Comment: @Rahul  here is my result  >>>  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at test.js:1         really sorry that i disturb you but i need to learn

Comment: edit your question, don't post your code here in the comments... :/

Comment: @vsync oh ok thanks

Comment: You have error in this code change to
`<script src="test.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: a result is show  like this         >>>  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at test.js:1
popup.html:1 Refused to load the script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquer%E0%B9%82%E2%82%AC%C2%8C%E0%B9%82%E2%82%AC%C2%8By.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".        :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
         alert("I found itttttt");
    }else{
         alert("jquery library not found ");
    }  

    var $ = jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log("ext loaded")
        $("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var consult = $("input#consult").val()
        var url = $("input#url").val()
        console.log(consult, url)
        // alert(consult+ url)
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url:"https://www.jbhired.com/admin/server/submitSearch.php",
              dataType: "jsonp",
              crossDomain: true,
              data : {
                consult: consult, 
                url: url
              },

            })
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I dont know how are you doing this, but I see " I found ittt"

Comment: " i found ittt'  i write for alert to find my jquery library

Comment: I know, Im not that noob to javascript. I was stating that in the code you posted there are no bugs, it shows that jquery is present.

Comment: sorry i dont mean you are noob  but i just explain

Comment: Don´t worry, there is no offense when none is taken ;)
Did you solve this question? @punchh

Comment: i can but still have another error show more  haha  cause i put a data in my textfield but there show an error  jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 Refused to load the script 'https://www.jbhired.com/admin/server/submitSearch.php?callback=jQuery321003675715372465249_1497940420192&consult=qwsa&url=&_=1497940420193' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".  like this

Comment: Refused to load the script 'https://www.jbhired.com/admin/server/submitSearch.php?callback=jQuery32101767394122710031_1497940566629&consult=fefef&url=fefef&_=1497940566630' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Comment: BUT read the documentation, please, this is insecure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935657/refused-to-load-the-image-because-it-violates-content-securtiy-policy-cordova